# Using MySQL Partitioning to speed up concurrent deletes and selects?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, partitioning

I have a MySQL Innodb table that contains about 8.5 million rows. The table structure basically looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydatatable` (
  `ext_data_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `datetime_utc` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ext_data_id`,`datetime_utc`,`type`),
  KEY `datetime_utc` (`datetime_utc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Every night, I delete the expired values from this table with the following query:

```
delete from mydatatable where datetime_utc < '2013-09-23'
```

This query does not seem to use indizes, and it takes quite some time to run. However I also get concurrent updates and selects on the same table. These get locked then, causing my website to be unresponsive at that time.

I am looking for various ways to speed up this setup. I cam across MySQL partitioning and I am wondering if this would be a good fit. I am always adding and selecting the newer data to this table and deleting old ones. I could create partitions based on something like MOD(DAYOFYEAR(datetime),4). Now when I delete, I will always delete the values from another partition than the one I am reading or writing from.

Will I experience locking with this setup? Will partitioning improve the query speed and availability in my case? Or should I look for another solution, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MySQL 5.5 you could use function [COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-range.html), that simplifies your partitioning for non-integer columns (such as datetime_utc).

As for the performance:

- Dropping a partition is a constant time operation for LIST and RANGE partitioning. The speed is equivalent of a `TRUNCATE TABLE` or `rm file`, so practically independent of the size of the partition.
- Doing `SELECT` on a partitioned table benefits from [partition pruning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-pruning.html), so that you read only from  the partition that match you search criteria. That can also speed up range  scans.

**Tip:**

Do not forget to add an "default" partition, such as

```
    PARTITION the_last_one VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE)
```

in order to avoid `INSERT/UPDATE` statements fail since no partition found to insert into.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you are on right track. You should create daily partitions here and store data in them, you queries will get revolutionised and will run like ferrari. Also take a look at local indexes.
Also with partitions, if your previous data will not interfere, so you can keep or delete it wont make much difference. In fact instead of deleteing you can simply drop partitions. This is also very fast.